# Downloading csv file from browser: NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I am trying to download the CSV file from the browser, but its not doing anything. The prof has given this code, and it works in his example, but isn't working in mine.

```
if ( !err ) {
                console.log("Working with: ",row.sheet);
                // convert to javascript object
                let values = JSON.parse( row.sheet );
                console.log("VALUES CONTAINS: ",values);
                let csv = ''
                for( let row of values ) {
                    csv += CSV.stringify( row ); 
                }
                console.log('sending csv ',csv);
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
                // tell the browsers to download to a file
                res.set('Content-Disposition',
                    `attachment; filename="${name}.csv"`);
                console.log('check status csv: ',csv);
                res.send( csv );
            }
```

The console.logs are all working, just the download isn't poping up

Comment: Check if your browser blocked downloads or not

Comment: try `res.set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="${name}.csv" '); `

Comment: The download will be "ajax" so without the rest of your code, debugging what you have shown is not possible.

Comment: @MohammedShabeerkp 

I think the backtick has to be there because I am using js amidst string